# Missing Some Response Headers

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am currently creating an API server using Node.js + Mongoose. Right now, I am facing a problem with one API. When I call that API with required headers (i.e. username, password, apikey)
in request, some headers are missing.

```
{
  "date": "Mon, 19 Oct 2015 07:16:05 GMT",
  "server": "nginx/1.6.2 (Ubuntu)",
  "x-powered-by": "Express",
  "etag": "\"-950978302\"",
  "access-control-allow-methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "access-control-allow-headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, USERNAME, PASSWORD, APIKEY, SECRETKEY, API_KEY, SECRET_KEY",
  "content-length": "3791"
}
```

But after update some data and I request with another headers, it is showing the result (not updated one) with headers below.

```
{
  "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
  "date": "Mon, 19 Oct 2015 07:28:24 GMT",
  "last-modified": "Mon, 19 Oct 2015 06:33:52 GMT",
  "server": "nginx/1.6.2 (Ubuntu)",
  "etag": "\"-35186508\"",
  "content-length": "944",
  "content-type": "application/json"
}
```

There is no `access-control-allow-headers`, `content-type`, `connection` and others in headers. I already set up headers inside my app.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, USERNAME, PASSWORD, APIKEY, SECRETKEY, API_KEY, SECRET_KEY");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  next();
});
```

Comment: I am facing same problem! Were you able to find some solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get headers like `USERNAME` , `PASSWORD`.

You should define custom headers with `X-` prefix. 
Add `X-` prefix to your custom headers which header you want to get.

There is [mozilla's doc about HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

*BTW , usually if you use token(apikey) based authentication you don't need username and password as header. Just pass them one time to authenticate user. Also you can pass that parameters as json and then every single request you will just need only the user's token(apikey).*